# Как остановить бесконечный поток из нового диалогового окна

Tags: c++, qt

Запустил бесконечный поток из окна mainwindow. Создал диалоговое окно menu по нажатию на кнопку мне нужно остановить бесконечный поток. Но как это сделать? Не ясно мне. Ведь указатель на бесконечный поток остался в mainwindow.

Вот я создал поток в mainwindow:

```
QThread* pThread = new QThread; 
threadbalancerautomode->moveToThread(pThread); 
QObject::connect(pThread, SIGNAL(started()), threadbalancerautomode, SLOT(slotStartAutoMode())); 
pThread->start();
```

Останавливаю поток из mainwindow:

```
if(threadbalancerautomode) { 
    threadbalancerautomode->slotStopAutoMode(); 
}
```

создал диалоговое окно menu_1 dialog;

```
dialog.setModal(true); 
dialog.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint); 
dialog.exec();
```

и как из него остановить поток не знаю?

Comment: пожалуйста уточните как вы запускаете поток

Answer (score 2):

У вашего бесконечного потока где-то внутри есть цикл, а у этого цикла есть условие завершения. Проверяйте в этом условии, что переменная типа `std::atomic<bool>` все еще истина, и если она стала ложной - выходите из цикла. Чтобы все работало и было чисто написано, желательно передать переменную в поток по константной ссылке.

Comment: не qt! ТСу нужно qt решение

Comment: @Andrey А Qt умеет останавливать бесконечные циклы? Как?

Comment: @Andrey используйте QAtomicInt xD https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qatomicint.html

Comment: А что Вы мне отвечаете? ТСу это пишите.

Comment: Вы останавливаете поток в MainWindow if(dialog.exec() == <Ok>) {
            _thread->quit(); // Завершаем поток
            _thread->wait(); // Ждем завершения
            // Идем дальше...
        }. А если я создам диалоговое окно menu то как мне там остановить поток?

Comment: @zhilenkov это к моему ответу вопрос. Отвечаю: нет ничего невозможного, - покажите код в вашем вопросе.

Comment: Вот я создал поток в mainwindow        QThread* pThread=new QThread;
       threadbalancerautomode->moveToThread(pThread);
       QObject::connect(pThread, SIGNAL(started()),
                        threadbalancerautomode, SLOT(slotStartAutoMode()));
       pThread->start(); Останавливаю поток  из mainwindow   if(threadbalancerautomode){
            threadbalancerautomode->slotStopAutoMode();
            }создал диалоговое окно     menu_1 dialog;
    dialog.setModal(true);
    dialog.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    dialog.exec(); и как из него остановить поток не знаю.

Comment: threadbalancerautomode -  вот в этой штуке объявите булеву переменную

Comment: И как к ней обратиться из другого окна?

Comment: Например так - в классе храните константную ссылку на переменную. В класс передаете эту самую ссылку при вызове конструктора (а иначе у вас и не получится). В родительском окне заводите слот, который будет в переменную писать false. Связываете из дочернего окна сигнал с этим слотом.

Comment: Вот честно скажу непонимание. Как можно передать указатель на поток. И вызвать метод для его остановки.

Comment: Покажите пример.

Answer (score 2):

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
    <какой-то метод, или конструктор>() {
        // создаем поток
        _thread = new MyThread();
        ...
    }

public slots:    
    void showDialog() {
        QDialog dialog = ...;

        if(dialog.exec() == <Ok>) {
            _thread->stop();
            // Идем дальше...
        }
    }
}
```

При этом поток может выглядеть, например так:

```
class MyThread : public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT 
    ...
public slots:
    void stop() {
        QMutexLocker locker(&_mutex);
        _active = false;
    }
protected: 
    void run() override {

        QMutexLocker locker(&_mutex);
        _active = true;
        locker.unlock();

        while(true) {
            locker.relock();
            if( !_active )
                break;
            locker.unlock();
            // делаем что-то бесконечное
        } 
    }
    ...
private:
    bool _active;
    QMutex _mutex;
}
```

**Дополнение** Если вы хотите остановить поток из диалога не закрывая его, то надо воспользоваться сигналами/слотами. Например, добавьте в ваш диалог сигнал, например, выбора пункта меню:

```
class MyDialog : public QDialog {
signals:
    void menuItemSelected(/*Здесь могли бы быть ваши аргументы*/);
}
```

Далее в основном окне, до вызова exec() у диалога, создаем коннект (в каком-либо методе главного окна приложения, mainwindow):

```
connect(&dialog, &MyDialog::menuItemSelected, this, [=](/*Аргументы из сигнала*/) {
    // Останавливаем поток
    if( pThread != nullptr ) {
        pThread->stop();
    }
});
// а теперь запускаем наш диалог
dialog.exec();
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы написать больше кода? Лично я за всеми этими многоточиями не вижу идею того, как это должно работать, а главное, наследники каких классов у вас создаются.

Comment: Я не понимаю, как это будет работать. Согласно мануалу, exec() встает и читает очередь сообщений, пока не получит из нее exit() или quit(). " // Спим, едим, ждем, считаем..." при этом выполняться не будет

Comment: @gbg если посылать exit с не нулевым аргументом, то цикл будет "прокручиваться". Можно сделать через wait и некий bool в while. Вопрос был не в этом (мы не знаем как у ТС реализовано), я бы расписал

Comment: На мой придирчивый взгляд, это лютые костыли. Получается, что цикл в потоке зависит сообщений, которые шлет родительский поток. Зачем тогда нужен вынос кода в отдельный поток? А если код тяжелый?

Comment: @gbg нет тут никаких котсылей. Обычное решение. Можно и через wait... Вопрос не про это

Comment: Еще раз, вы осознаете, что на каждую итерацию цикла нужно дожидаться откуда-то сигнала, разрешающего эту итерациюи? А что будет, если мы перемножаем огромные массивы? А что будет с кешами при таком разрыве цикла?

Comment: @gbg а если код тяжёлый и если перемножаем огромные массивы, то тем более нужен, фоновый к основному, поток.